# How is the word "nay" used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, quotes

I've been trying to figure out the meaning of the following quotation from the [*Discourses on Livy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=a3hylAentHAC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=The+mass+of+mankind+accept+what+seems+as+what+is;+nay,+are+often%3E+touched+more+nearly+by+appearances+than+by+realities&source=bl&ots=HzhIg_YF5p&sig=S_5bPdlV6tVqnr3BxRQGyFlnB2E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid0KeB5JvLAhWLkYMKHRg_Dx4Q6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=The%20mass%20of%20mankind%20accept%20what%20seems%20as%20what%20is%3B%20nay%2C%20are%20often%3E%20touched%20more%20nearly%20by%20appearances%20than%20by%20realities&f=false) by Niccolo Machiavelli, translated by Ninian Hill Thomson:

> The mass of mankind accept what seems as what is; nay, are often
>   touched more nearly by appearances than by realities.

In particular, I don't understand the use of the word "nay" here. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

'Nay' is old English for 'no' and 'moreover'.
The writer is correcting himself in this narrative. Often, such a correction paves the way for a more accurate expression of his or her thoughts.

> Has many good, nay, noble qualities.
>   He was well-liked, nay, worshipped.

Comment: Agreed, although you need a semicolon between well-liked and nay, I think (I believe there's an implied subject and verb in the second clause).

Comment: Intuitively, the semicolon might not look out of place indeed, but the examples in the dictionary are with just commas. I did just find [an article](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html) about semicolon usage, but I'm falling asleep here, so I'm saving that read for tomorrow.

Comment: Hm? That's interesting; the newer books I've got seem to use a comma, whereas the older ones that I have seem to use the semicolon.

Comment: How about using dashes? 
`Has many good - nay, noble - qualities.`